# How can I get a list of installed fonts on Windows, using unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I've explored a bit, and so far I've found EnumFontFamiliesEx(...). However, it looks like this function is used to return all the charsets for a given font (e.g. "Arial").

I can't quite figure out how to get the list of installed fonts to begin with. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
LOGFONT lf;
lf.lfFaceName[0] = '\0';
lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
HDC hDC = ::GetDC();
EnumFontFamiliesEx(hDC, &lf, (FONTENUMPROC)&EnumFontFamExProc, 0, 0);
ReleaseDC(hDC);
```

Then define a callback function:

```
int CALLBACK EnumFontFamExProc(
   ENUMLOGFONTEX *lpelfe,
  NEWTEXTMETRICEX *lpntme,
  DWORD FontType,
  LPARAM lParam
  )
{
    AfxMessageBox(lpelfe->elfFullName);

    //Return non--zero to continue enumeration
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/fonthandlinganddetection/article.php/c157), as the code there explains how to use the `EnumFontFamiliesEx` to get all the font names.